# Objective-C numberOfSectionsInTableView - Query to return sections alphabetically

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview

I currently have a working TableView Application with a back-end sqlite database to feed the data.  The first view returns all states with a static heading of "States".  I would like to change that to return the states in alphabetical sections (ex. Alabama, Alaska, Arizona, Arkansas would fall under section called 'A' -- California, Colorado, Connecticut would fall under a section called 'C', etc).

My appdelegate calls a query to 'select id, state from state'.  I have what I believe to be working code to create the sections below (I have tested this by creating a NSMutableArray with just states as the objects and it worked fine).

```
stateIndex = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

for (int i=0; i<[listOfStates count]-1; i++){
    //---get the first char of each state---
    char alphabet = [[listOfStates objectAtIndex:i] characterAtIndex:0];
    NSString *uniChar = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%C", alphabet];

    //---add each letter to the index array---
    if (![stateIndex containsObject:uniChar])
    {            
        [stateIndex addObject:uniChar];
    }        
}
```

With no warnings/errors, I run simulator but it crashes.  After a short while, it dawned on me as to why it is crashing.  I am attempting to look for a alphabetical character during the search but due to the fact that the original query calls both an id and the state name, it is looking at the id and failing.  The id is needed in the search as it is linked to another table that loads cities based upon the state selected.  the id is the primary key.

So, my question is...IS there a way to strip off or have the id field skipped during this search to create the alphabetical sections?

Thank you in advance!

UPDATED SchoolHouse.h ========

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <sqlite3.h>

@interface SchoolHouse : NSObject {

}

@property (assign, nonatomic, readonly) NSInteger schoolHouseID;
@property (copy, nonatomic) NSString *schoolHouseName;


-(id) initWithSchoolHouseData:(NSInteger)pk schoolHouseName:(NSString *)name;

@end
```

Comment: If something's crashing it would be helpful to post what kind of crash logs or messages from the debugger you get. You should also try to help us understand what kind of objects are inside listOfStates - just `NSString`s?

Comment: Hi, In regards to the crash logs...It indicates "Invalid character at Index"...Which I took for it seeing the id (number) and not being a character when combing through the list.  As far as what objects are inside of listOfStates...It's the NSMutableArray containing the results of the sqlquery "select id, state from states".

Comment: I can see from the code that `listOfStates` is an NSMutableArray - I'm asking what class are the objects inside? What are their descriptions when you do, say `po [listOfStates objectAtIndex:0]` in the debugger?

Answer (score 0):

Please see new code below.

I'm guessing the reason it was crashing is because some of the strings in your mutable array were zero length (`@""`) and you can't get the first letter from an empty string. I've added a check to stop cater for this. Your `for` loop condition was also going to skip the last element, so I've fixed that. Also, I'm forcing the first letter to be upper case so `@"New York"` and `@"nevada"` both go under `@"N"` (just to make the code more robust. Let me know if this still doesn't work for you:

Edited to work with an array of `SchoolHouse` objects.

At the top of your file, make sure you have:

```
#include "SchoolHouse.h"
```

Then replace the code you have with:

```
NSMutableArray *stateIndex = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

for (int i=0; i < [listOfStates count]; i++) {
    SchoolHouse *schoolHouse = [listOfStates objectAtIndex:i];

    //---skip the object if it's the wrong class---
    if (![schoolHouse isKindOfClass:[SchoolHouse class]]) continue;

    //---skip the object if it's name is empty---
    if (schoolHouse.schoolHouseName.length == 0) continue;

    //---get the first char of the name---
    unichar firstChar = [schoolHouse.schoolHouseName characterAtIndex:0];
    NSString *charString = [[NSString stringWithCharacters:&firstChar length:1] uppercaseString];

    //---add each letter to the index array---
    if (![stateIndex containsObject:charString]) {
        [stateIndex addObject:charString];
    }
}
```

Comment: Ander, Thank you very much for this reply!!  It certainly makes a lot of sense.  I appreciate it tremendously.  I will have to wait until this afternoon to give it a try but it certainly looks promising.  I will respond back.  Thanks again!!!

Comment: I just got home here and gave it a try.  I got a different error code this time that now reads....                                 Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSArrayM length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8050180'

Comment: The code above assumed that `listOfStates` was an array of `NSString` objects. I've updated it to work for an array of string arrays. If this still doesn't work, do a `NSLog(@"%@", listOfStates);` and show me the output.

Comment: @Anders Thanks for working with me on this and providing the tweak.  I tried it with the update that you provided.  It still is crashing in the debugger.  I have included an NSLog as you have suggested.  The details are:   _(
        "<SchoolHouse: 0x802e650>",
        "<SchoolHouse: 0x802a4c0>",

Comment: It provides 51 <SchoolHouse: 0x802...) returns...Followed by 2012-09-03 20:50:12.333 CollegeInfoLITE[63229:c07] -[SchoolHouse characterAtIndex:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x802e650.  Please let me know if I can provide any more information.  Again, I appreciate your time working with me on this.  Thank you.

Comment: So `stateIndex` is mutable array of custom objects of type `SchoolHouse`. I will need to see the contents of `SchoolHouse.h` to fix the code.

Comment: @Anders.  Yes, that is correct.  I have included the SchoolHouse.h file to my original posting.  Thank you very much!!!

Comment: @user1542684 There is no "state" data member in the `SchoolHouse` class. There is no way to create an index of states with no states. Did you want an index on the `schoolHouseName` property?

Comment: @Anders  I understand now.  Yes, being able to create an index on the schoolHouseName would be fine.  Thank you!

Comment: @Anders.  Sorry for the delay.  I just got in the door here and gave it a try.  Funny thing is that...It did not crash this go around, the simulator did not crash....There was also no output generated.  The simulator opens but no data is presented.  it is just a blank grouped tableview background.

Comment: If you remove the line `if (![schoolHouse isKindOfClass:[SchoolHouse class]]) continue;` does it crash?

Comment: @Anders. I just removed the line and it does not crash.  The behavior is the same as it was with the line in there.

Comment: @user1542684 okay then, now put that line back and remove the `if (schoolHouse.schoolHouseName.length == 0) continue;` line. Does it crash now?